# PHP script returning "Response does not contain any data"

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this PHP script that let me get photo objects from MySQL database, while fetching the results with mysql_fetch_array() function I push the row into an array. Which works, simple and good.

After the while, I do an echo of the array size and it does work too.
Then, when I try to encode the array to json format and I test it I get "Response does not contain any data" with a Ok status from Chrome's Advanced Rest Client.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
// looping through all results
// photo node
$response["photos"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp photo array
    $photo = array();

    $photo["photoid"] = $row["photoid"];
    $photo["photodescription"] = $row["photodescription"];
    $photo["uploaderid"] = $row["uploaderid"];
    $photo["takenat"] = $row["takenat"];
    $photo["nblikes"] = $row["nblikes"];
    $photo["photourl"] = $row["photourl"];
    $photo["thumbnailurl"] = $row["thumbnailurl"];


    // push single photo into final response array
    array_push($response["photos"], $photo);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo sizeof($response["photos"]);
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Can anyone help, please ?

Comment: Where do you see that error message? Are you returning this data to Javascript? Could be facing `CURSE` of the `CORS`

Comment: What do you see in red block of this link ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: what does var_dump($response); give you?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky that message is the result that the Advanced Rest Client App for Chrome gives me.

Comment: @zlen, I do know that, but I have written many other scripts which works fine even with that.

Comment: @Hamzaaton yes but it wont work in php7, it is removed. Why not just use something that has not been deprecated soo long ago? Also, what did the var dump give you`?

Comment: @OllyTenerife, it gives me the result I do want. A table containing all the data I need.

Comment: @RonniSkansing, it gave the exact result I needed.

Comment: @Hamzaaton what does var_dump(json_encode($response)) then give you?

Comment: @RonniSkansing a blank table 

<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>boolean</small> <font color='#75507b'>false</font>
</pre>

Comment: @Hamzaaton well there is your answer, the json_encode fails (the input is not a proper format) the function return a boolean false, which you cant really echo out, hence the empty response. To debug it, go back to the `var_dump($response)` and consider why the input can not be used in json_encode

Comment: @Hamzaaton for extra debugging points you might use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: You are welcome @Hamzaaton have fun coding =]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to RonnySkansing, it appeared that I had an error while encoding. Which is a "JSON_ERROR_UTF8: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"

I've added then this : mysql_set_charset("utf8");
And it's done. 
Voila.

Answer (score 0):

Your select probably has an error or the number of rows is 0. Try printing the numbers of rows.

```
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Nope, tried the request on MySQL and it works fine. 
Also the var_dump shows that it works.

Comment: Size of will always print something so it can't be hitting that line if you're not getting a response.